# spring cloud vault - approle authentication without secret id

Tags: spring, hashicorp-vault

I need to connect to vault (pull mode) using approle based authentication. I am using using spring-cloud-vault. I have the role name and role id but the secret id is dynamic, so cannot use it in bootstrap.yml. Can someone please help?
Is there a way to pull the secret id dynamically based on role id?

```
spring:
 application.name: xxxx
 cloud.vault:
  scheme: xxxx
  host: xxxx
  port: xxxx
  authentication: APPROLE        
  app-role:  
    app-role-path: xxxx
    role-id: xxxx
    #secret-id: UNKNOWN
```

Comment: Please review [ask]

Comment: That's not yet possible: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-vault/issues/174. Workaround: Configure a `ClientAuthentication` bean in the bootstrap context yourself.

Comment: fixed in spring-config-vault 2.1. See https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-vault/issues/222